# Understanding Enterprise Integration for Scatter Gather?

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I'm looking to better understand multiple splitters, transformers and aggregation methods in the popular EIP scatter gather.

Use-case is I send in some XML that can correspond to a multitude of different types. I want to split on the type specified in the header (Different for each type) and run it through a specific transformer corresponding to each type.

Are there any good examples within Camel to do something like this?

#### Pseudo Code Idea

```
RouteBuilder to process the input XML

Split on the type

Dynamically redirect to proper splitter based on type

Dynamically redirect to proper transformer based on type

Aggregate

Return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Whatever you are looking to achieve is possible using camel. I cannot able to provide you complete set, but can able to help you how each process has to done.

--RouteBuilder to process the input XML : [File Process](http://camel.apache.org/file.html) refer this which will help you to read file from specific directory.

--Split on the type : [Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) using xpath you can able to pick type.

--Dynamically redirect to proper transformer based on type : [Data format](http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html) based on data format you can marshal/un-marshal any type of data.

--Aggregate: [Aggregate](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html)

--Return response : Once above done you have result you can done what ever you has to done after that.